# Defining a function to call a video within Jupyter Notebook

Tags: function, jupyter-notebook

I have a small piece of code which displays an mp4 video within the Jupyter notebook. However, I wish to hide this code away within a callable module, so I need to nest it within a function. However, calling the function doesn't send the video to my display.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
import base64
import io

def qq ():
    video = io.open('/Users/.../video.mp4', 'r+b').read()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(video)
    return(HTML(data='''<video width="160" height="120" controls>
    <source src="data:video/mp4;base64,{0}" type="video/mp4" /
    </video>'''.format(encoded.decode('ascii'))))

qq
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error message:

```
<function __main__.qq>
```

Comment: Try call `qq()`

Comment: My original text misses parentheses in the function call!!
Oops!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to call the function using parentheses. Noob error!

```
from IPython.display import HTML
import base64
import io

def play():
    video = io.open('/Users/thescoop/Dropbox/BlotMan/BlotManResources/ForKaren.mp4', 'r+b').read()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(video)
    return(HTML(data='''<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="data:video/mp4;base64,{0}" type="video/mp4" /></video>'''.format(encoded.decode('ascii'))))

play()
```